# Angularjs: Select all checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement select all checkbox (for multiple delete).

**This is my View script:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_all" id="chk_all"  ng-click="checkAll(this)" /> Select All
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in allUsers">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="list" name="list[]" class="chk_all" value="{{user.user_id}}" id="{{user.user_id}}"  ng-checked="checkedAll"  /></td>
    <td>{{user.username}}</td>
    <td>{{user.fname}}</td>
    <td>{{user.lname}}</td>
    <td>{{user.mobile}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td><a title="Edit User" href="#/edit_user/{{user.user_id}}" ><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a> | <a title="Delete User"  id=""  style="cursor:pointer;"  ng-click="delete_user(user.user_id)" ><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On `"chk_all"` checkbox following all checkbox should checked or unchecked.

I want to delete selected users on button click. So **how can i get selected user id's on http post method**.

Script written as:

```
$scope.testFunction=function(params)
        {
            $http.post("../admin/users/testFunction",{'params' : params}) 
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) 
                { 
                console.log(data);
                alert(1);
                })

                .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

                });
        }
```

controller function:

```
public function testFunction()
    {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        print($data->params);
    }
```

In testFunction (php function), how can I retrive selected user id's ?
Any solution?
**Note:** I have done it with javascript and php. Now application is going to convert into Angularjs, so it should be in angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the object 'user' a property: 'checked', then the checkbox looks like:  `<input type="checkbox" name="list[]" class="chk_all" ng-model="user.checked" onclick="uncheck_select_all(this)" />`. Then on your submit, you check for each user in allUsers whether user.checked == true and if so push that user to an array. Then put that array in your http post and handle deletion for each user in the array at the server side.

**Update**

In [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/GA7VIreTloBtzBzEJaVg?p=preview) plnkr I show what I meant with my answer + comments. This doesnt work if you simply copy-paste because I used some different namings. If you can't figure out the solution with this plunker, I'm afraid I did all I could. Note: You could replace the angular.forEach loops with regular for-loops for slightly faster performance.

Comment: how can i set user.user_id to checkbox?
is there any sample code?

Comment: If you iterate through allUsers in your submit, if the property user.checked == true, you can put user.user_id in an array. But if you purely want the user.user_id as value of the checkbox you can simply add `value="{{user.user_id}}"` to you checkbox

Comment: Ok. Fine. I have done with setting value to checkbox. as value="{{user.user_id}}". Now I want to checkall or uncheck all.

Comment: You can use ng-checked for that as area28 stated in his answer. You can also iterate through allUsers and set all user.checked properties to true in your checkAll(this) function.

Comment: area28 has given only check all. how to uncheck all?

Comment: You said you knew javascript and php right? area28's checkAll function could be simply changed to: `$scope.toggleCheckAll = function() { $scope.checkedAll = !$scope.checkedAll; }` this will either check them all or uncheck them all

Comment: Ok. Fine. Check all and uncheck all is working, but when I click any of the selected checkbox, check_all checkbox should get unchecked.
How?

Comment: If you haven't got a clue how to handle something like that, I suggest you read into the angular documentation first. Did you even try to solve this yourself? You could use a `$scope.$watch` expression to see if allUsers changes (since a property change of user.checked would mean the object allUsers changes), then iterate through allUsers and if one of the user.checked == false, set `$scope.checkedAll` to false (and/or make it indeterminate).

Comment: First of all, Do i need to use user.checked in my code? I am asking because I dont want to set this false initially for 1000 users, instead i want to set value and after post i just want to get checked entries. Tell me if I am on wrong way.

Comment: To be honest, if you had this working in JavaScript, you could just use the same approach for angular while browsing google on how to adjust certain things (like ng-checked, ng-change, ng-click) to angular. I suggested a method, but there are plenty of other methods. You could use an on-change method that adds the value of the changed checkbox to an array and then post that array on your submit aswell..

Comment: See, I am doing all things with angularjs,like, pagination,filtering,sorting,adding users, updating users,deleting single user.So, if I handle THIS  with javascript and php, is this right? It will co-operate with angular?

Comment: Angular is a 'library' based on javascript, a lot of javascript or jquery's functionality can also be used in angular, or atleast angular uses the same approach. So compare your JavaScript code to the angular code you have at the moment, and then try to create the angular way you want to use. If you have enough experience with angular/javascript this shouldn't cause to much trouble. You also have enough pointers and guidelines in this stackoverflow post now.

Comment: Ive typed in 'angular checkbox example' in google and this angular documentation page popped up, which gives a nice example. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: I have seen it. I want selected users at backend. Is there any way other than user.checked=true ?

Comment: Sigh, I've been trying to tell you for like 5 comments now. I'll create a fiddle

Comment: Hey, I have changed code, Question details edited as per changes. All the changes are as per your suggestions. Please look over the code. Kindly revert back (if possible).

Comment: I had tried your Plunker. Its giving error:  Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24elementProvider%20%3C-%20%24element%20%3C-%20allUsersCtrl

Comment: More specified: Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- allUsersCtrl

Comment: Question updated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907054/angularjs-select-all-checkbox-to-delete-multiple-users

Comment: Solved. If the question is hepls to reasearch, do upvote for QUESTION.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `ng-checked` in the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

You can add an expression to every checkbox you want checked based on a `$scope` variable.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_all" id="chk_all"  ng-click="checkAll(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_1" id="chk_1"  ng-checked="checkedAll" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_2" id="chk_2"  ng-checked="checkedAll" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_3" id="chk_3"  ng-checked="checkedAll" />
```

In your controller you would have this:

```
$scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.checkedAll = true;
}
```

This will set the `$scope.checkedAll` variable to true making the `ng-checked` expression true, which will check all checkboxes using that expression.

I changed the `onchange` attribute to `ng-click` as well.