# Angularjs: select all checkbox to delete multiple users

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement select all checkbox (**for multiple delete**).
I have tried the code given in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GA7VIreTloBtzBzEJaVg?p=preview). Its giving the following  **error**:

```
 `Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- allUsersCtrl`
```

Can you provide any solution or shed some light on where i have gone wrong!
This is the script:

```
var angularControllers = angular.module('angularControllers', ['flash']);  
angularControllers.controller('allUsersCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$element', function($scope,$http,$element){
// $scope.allUsers contains users
//delete multiple
      $scope.arrayToPost = [];
      $scope.checkedAll = false;
      angular.forEach($scope.allUsers, function(user) {
        user["checked"] = false;
        });

        $scope.toggleCheckAll = function() {
       if($scope.checkedAll) {
         angular.forEach($scope.allUsers, function(user) {
           user.checked = true
            $scope.modifyArrayToPost(user);
         });
       }
       else {
         angular.forEach($scope.allUsers, function(user) {
           user.checked = false;
            $scope.modifyArrayToPost(user);
         });
       }

     }

      $scope.modifyArrayToPost = function(user) {
       if(user.checked && $scope.arrayToPost.indexOf(user.user_id) == -1){
         $scope.arrayToPost.push(user.user_id);
       }
       else if(!user.checked) {
         $scope.arrayToPost.splice($scope.arrayToPost.indexOf(user.user_id), 1);
       }
     }

      $scope.$watch('allUsers', function() {
       var allSet = true;
       var allClear = true;
       angular.forEach($scope.allUsers, function(user) {
          if (user.checked) {
            allClear = false;
          } else {
            allSet = false;
          }         
       });

       var checkAll = $element.find('#all');
       checkAll.prop('indeterminate', false);
       if (allSet) {
          $scope.checkedAll = true;
       } else if (allClear) {
          $scope.checkedAll = false;
       } else {
          $scope.checkedAll = false;
          checkAll.prop('indeterminate', true);
       }
     }, true);

        $scope.testFunction=function(params)
        {
        console.log(params);
            $http.post("../admin/users/testFunction",{'params' : params}) 
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) 
                { 
                console.log(data);
                }) 
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

                });
        }

}]); //allUsersCtrl
```

This is the view:

```
<form  action="" method="post" name="myform" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="chk_all"  ng-model="checkedAll" id="all"  ng-change="toggleCheckAll()" /> Select All
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">  
        <tr ng-repeat="user in allUsers">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked"  class="chk_all" value="{{user.id}}" ng-change="modifyArrayToPost(user)"  /></td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
<input type="submit" value="test" ng-click="testFunction(arrayToPost)"/>
 <tt>array: {{arrayToPost}}</tt>
</form>
```

I want to delete selected users on button click. Please help.

Comment: Simply put, there is no `$element` provider. You should really use a directive for controlling the DOM

Comment: when are you getting this error?

Comment: @DivyaMV: at console, when I put and run  this code. I didn't used protractor.js code anywhere, even I didn't included the protractor.js.
I doubt on this:  `$element.find('#all');
       checkAll.prop('indeterminate', false);`

Comment: the plunker doesnt throw any errors,but this can come when you are trying to inject $element to any of the controllers/services.In the plunker `ExampleController` has that rightly injected.

Comment: I also has rightly injected, as i think. If I do like this: `var checkAll=angular.element.find('#all')` Its not giving elementprovider error. Its giving error for next line: `checkAll.prop('indeterminate', false);`
Error: 
`Error: checkAll.prop is not a function`

Comment: $element should not be injected to any controller in the plunker example it works fine bcs `exampleController` is associated with a `form` tag.i don't think its the same in ur case

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/divm/6LtLfmdw/ check this fiddle to implement a check All solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494825/error-unknown-provider-elementprovider-element

Comment: @DivyaMV in your fiddle, if you manually select all items, the checkall checkbox isnt checked.

Comment: Are you using Jquery in your app sujvan? And if so, is it included before the angular library? I believe including Jquery will solve the $element provider error. You don't have to use it though, $element is basicly a replacement for the Jquery equivalent `$('#all').prop('indeterminate', true)`

Comment: @Guinn:  Hi, Guinn, I succeed! I used your code. But just did small change: removed `$element` from module, from everywhere. And used `angular.element` directly.Two lines affected after removel of `$element ` as: `var checkAll=angular.element.find('#all');
   $(checkAll).prop('indeterminate', false);`

Comment: Good to hear. If my code solved your problem, could you mark my answer in your previous question the accepted answer then?

Comment: If the question is hepls to reasearch, do upvote for QUESTION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
@Guinn:  Hi, Guinn, I succeed! I used your code.
But just did small change: removed `$element` from module, from everywhere. And used `angular.element` directly.

Two lines affected after removel of `$element` as:

```
var checkAll=angular.element.find('#all');
$(checkAll).prop('indeterminate', false);`
```

This link helps: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element